# Convert the month to always be 2 digits (eg 02)

Tags: r, date

I have the month in the usual format (2, 3, 4, and so on) but I wish to always have it in a 2 digit format so this would become (02, 03, 10, 11, 12).

Currently what I have as just;

```
themonth = month(Sys.Date())
```

I've tried putting as.numeric around this but out of ideas pretty quickly on this one

Comment: Try: `substr(Sys.Date(), 6, 7)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`

```r
sprintf('%02d', lubridate::month(Sys.Date()))
#> [1] "02"
```

With a double digit month, there is no leading 0.

```r
sprintf('%02d', lubridate::month(as.Date('2023-10-01')))
[1] "10"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
format(Sys.Date(), "%m")
# [1] "02"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `ifelse`

```
x <- lubridate::month(Sys.Date())
ifelse(nchar(x) == 1, paste0(0, x), x)
[1] "02"
```